# Can setInterval in javascript slow down my website

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I have create a website and I want to load data with fetch api of javascript.
So I want to update data without refresh page.

I used this way:

```
function GetData(){
    fetch('/post_data',{
        method : 'GET'
    })
    .then((respone)=>{
        return respone.json()
    })
    .then((data)=>{
        console.log(data)
        //Code
    })
}

window.onload = setInterval(GetData, 1000);
```

Can setInterval slow down my website if I use it more in my web pages?

Comment: Probably. You can always use your browser’s built-in profiler to monitor the performance of your applications. Consider using [Web Sockets](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) instead of polling, though.

Comment: `window.onload = setInterval(GetData, 1000);` <-- There's at least 3 things wrong here...

Comment: @SebastianSimon Instead of web-sockets or client polling, for one-way activites like this I'd recommend [SSE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events) (it uses much less server-side resources than a WebSocket does).

Comment: ...why are you making a `GET` request to endpoint named `post_data` ?

Comment: Why are you wondering if `setInterval` can cause performance issues? You should be using it for what it does: call a callback at a given interval of time. If you need this to happen, then `setInterval()` is indeed one of the best candidates for the job. If you're wondering if fetching your endpoint every seconds is the way to go to do what you want to do, then ask that, and explain to us what it is that you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

> I have create a website and I want to load data with fetch api of javascript. So I want to update data without refresh page.

OK

> I used this way:
>
> ```
> ...
> ```
>
> Can `setInterval` slow down my website if I use it more in my web pages?

In a word, **no**: there is nothing *inherent* in the `window.setInterval` (and its sister: `window.setTimeout`) functions that would present any kind of *performance* issue for a web-browser, **assuming** *that you use the functions correctly* - and *as-it-is* the code in your post shows that you are not using `setInterval` correctly.

---

Consider this quick reimplementation I did:

```js
/* Have some HTML like this:

    <label><input type="checkbox" id="toggle" checked /> Refresh data every 5 seconds</label>

    <output id="someOutputElement"></output>

    <button type="button" onclick="if(window.dataRefreshTimerId){window.clearInterval(window.dataRefreshTimerId); this.disabled = true;}">Emergency stop</button>

*/

async function getDataAndUpdatePageOnce() {

    const toggleEl = document.getElementById( 'toggle' );
    const outputEl = document.getElementById( 'someOutputElement' );

    if( toggleEl.checked === false ) return; // Simply returning-early when data-refreshing is disabled is much easier than faffing around with stopping and restarting the setInterval-based loop.

    try {
        const resp = await fetch( '/post_data', { method: 'GET' } );
        if( resp.ok && resp.headers.get('Content-Type') === 'application/json' ) {
            const dataFromJson = await resp.json();

            // Show the data in the page via the DOM, e.g.:
            outputEl.textContent = dataFromJson;
        }
        else {
            debugger;
            throw new Error( "Unexpected response: " + resp.status );
        }
    }    
    catch( err ) {
        debugger;
        console.error( err );
        outputEl.textContent = ( err || 'noidea' ).toString();
    }
}

window.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', onDOMContentLoaded );

var dataRefreshTimerId = null; // <-- top-level `var` variables are also `window` properties. Hence the `window.dataRefreshTimerId` in the `onclick=""` in the HTML.

function onDOMContentLoaded( e ) {

    dataRefreshTimerId = window.setInterval( getDataAndUpdatePageOnce, 5000 );
}
```